# How to get details of changes made to svn through eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a simple eclipse plugin. 
I want to get details such as the time of last commit, number of different authors. Size in kb of the files.

I want to get these details programmatically. I am using google host svn. I am using subclipse plugin to access svn through eclipse. I am using java. How do I proceed to reach my objective?

Comment: Can use just use shell script, sed, and awk? How hard is your java requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) and the [wiki](http://wiki.svnkit.com/SVNKit_FAQ). For commit related info as you asked for take a look at the [SVNCommitInfo](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/index.html) class:-

> The SVNCommitInfo class represents
>   information about a committed
>   revision. Commit information includes:
>
> ```
> a revision number;
> a datestamp when the revision was committed;
> the name of the revision author.
> ```
>
> In addition, this class provides
>   anexception that, if a commit has
>   failed, has got a description of a
>   failure reason.

[SVNDirEntry](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/SVNDirEntry.html) class is also useful for your purposes:-

> SVNDirEntry keeps an entry name, entry
>   kind (is it a file or directory), file
>   size (in case an entry is a file), the
>   last changed revision, the date when
>   the entry was last changed, the name
>   of the author who last changed the
>   entry, the commit log message for the
>   last changed revision. SVNDirEntry
>   also knows if the entry has any
>   properties.